# Pointer arrays allocated with malloc/calloc initializing with values other than 0

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have been given a school assignment in C to create a program that multiplies matrices. I will list assignment constraints below so people don't respond with questions as to why I am doing things this way.
Constraints from instructor:

- Cannot use square brackets anywhere in code (use pointer notation instead)
- Matrices A, B, C must be single integer pointer variables (int *A, *B, *C)
- Can only use main function and those specified by header
- Must compile with "gcc -ansi -Wall -o p2 p2.c"

I have not implemented the matrix multiplication function yet, as the issues I am having relate to either file reading or memory allocation.

The specific problem I am having is when I allocate space to the pointer matrix with either malloc OR calloc (tried both), the program inserts 33 in some places in the output instead of 0. I've tried everything at this point and am convinced my knowledge of pointers is fundamentally flawed.

p2.h (given by instructor)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
/* This function reads m, n, and p from the datafile.  
    It then allocates the correct amount of memory required for matrices
    A, B, and C.
    Then matrices A and B are filled from the datafile.
    The values for m, n, and p are passed by reference, and are
    thus filled in by this function
    PARAMETERS in order are:
    int **      matrix A
    int **      matrix B
    int **      matrix C    
    int *       m   The number of rows in matrix A
    int *       n   The number of columns in matrix A and
                    The number of rows in matrix B
    int *       p   The number of columns in matrix B
    char *      The name of the datafile, from the command line
*/
void read_matrices(int **, int **, int **,  int *, int *, int *, char *);
/*  This function prints a matrix.  Rows and columns should be preserved.
    PARAMETERS in order are:
    int *       The matrix to print
    int         The number of rows in the matrix
    int         The number of columns in the matrix
*/    
void print_matrix(int *, int, int);
/*  The two matrices A and B are multiplied, and matrix C contains the
    result.
    PARAMETERS in order are:
    int *       Matrix A
    int *       Matrix B
    int *       Matrix C
    int         m
    int         n
    int         p
*/    
void mult_matrices(int *, int *, int *, int, int, int);
```

p2.c (sorry for the mess a lot of debugging went on)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "./p2.h"

/* constants for testing */
#define cM 3
#define cN 2
#define cP 5

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Must include an argument.\n");
        exit(1);    
    }
    char *path = *(argv + 1);

    int *m = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
    int *n = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
    int *p = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
    *m = cM; *n = cN; *p = cP;

    int i,j; /* loop counters */
    /* allocate space for 2d pointer arrays */
    int **A = NULL; 
    A = (int **) malloc(*m * sizeof(int *));
    for (i = 0; i < *m; i++) {
        *(A+i) = (int *) malloc(*n * sizeof(int)); 
    }   

    int **B = NULL;
    B = (int **) malloc(*n * sizeof(int *));
    for (i = 0; i < *n; i++) {
        *(B+i) = (int *) malloc(*p * sizeof(int)); 
    }   

    int **C = NULL;
    C = (int **) malloc(*m * sizeof(int *));
    for (i = 0; i < *m; i++) {
        *(C+i) = (int *) malloc(*p * sizeof(int)); 
    }   

    /* write data to A */
    for (i = 0; i < *m; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < *n; j++) {
            *(*(A+i)+j) = 0;    
        }
    }

    /* testing a */
    for (i = 0; i < *m; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < *n; j++) {
            if (*(*(A+i)+j) != 0) {
                printf("[x]");
            } else {
                printf("[0]");  
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n");

    /* write data to B */
    for (i = 0; i < *n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < *p; j++) {
            *(*(B+i)+j) = 0;    
        }
    }

    /* testing b */
    for (i = 0; i < *n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < *p; j++) {
            if (*(*(B+i)+j) != 0) {
                printf("[x]");
            } else {
                printf("[0]");  
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n");

    /* write data to C */
    for (i = 0; i < *m; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < *p; j++) {
            *(*(C+i)+j) = 0;    
        }
    }

    /* testing c */
    for (i = 0; i < *m; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < *p; j++) {
            if (*(*(C+i)+j) != 0) {
                printf("[x]");
            } else {
                printf("[0]");
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n");



    printf("Matrix A: \n");
    print_matrix(*A, *m, *n);
    printf("Matrix B: \n");
    print_matrix(*B, *n, *p);
    printf("Matrix C: \n");
    print_matrix(*C, *m, *p);

    return 0;
}

void read_matrices(int **A, int **B, int **C, int *m, int *n, int *p, char *path) {
    FILE *fptr;
    fptr = fopen(path, "r");
    if (fptr == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot open file: ./p2 [filename].txt\n");  
        exit(1);
    }

    /* get first 3 numbers from file, set m,n,p */
    *m = fgetc(fptr);
    fgetc(fptr);
    *n = fgetc(fptr);
    fgetc(fptr);
    *p = fgetc(fptr);
    fgetc(fptr);

    /* read first matrix */
    /* 1) calculate matrix size m x n
     * 2) loop through malloc'ed matrix
     * 3) each loop, insert char in loc
     * 4) if next char NOT 10/32, add nextchar*10 to value in loc 
     */
    char cur;
    while ( (cur = fgetc(fptr)) != EOF ) {
        if (cur == 10 || cur == 32) {
            /* do nothing :) */
        } else {
            *m = cur;
            *n = cur;
            *p = cur;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    printf("m: %c\n", *m);
    printf("n: %c\n", *n);
    printf("p: %c\n", *p);
    printf("next: %c\n", fgetc(fptr));

    fclose(fptr);
}

void print_matrix(int *X, int rows, int cols) {
    int r, c;
    int k = 0;
    for (r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        for (c = 0; c < cols; c++)  {
            printf("\t%d", *(X+k));
            k++;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void mult_matrices(int *A, int *B, int *C, int m, int n, int p) {

}
```

d2.txt (data file)

```
3
2
4
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14
```

Output: ./p2 d2.txt

```
[0][0][0][0][0][0]
[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0]
[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0]
Matrix A:
        0       0
        0       0
        0       0
Matrix B:
        0       0       0       0       0
        0       33      0       0       0
Matrix C:
        0       0       0       0       0
        0       33      0       0       0
        0       0       0       0       33
```

If you notice, I have some debug code that checks whether or not the current item in the array is 0. It seems to indicate that they are all 0, making me think it is a printing problem, but I am even more lost on what would be causing that. The ascii code for 33 is an exclamation point, but I am not sure what relevance it has.

Comment: You are allocating a form of 2D array. But then your `print_matrix` function treats it as a 1D array. It seems the task requires you to allocate a 1D array instead because it says the matrices need to be single level pointers `int *`.

Comment: <O/T> `m`, `n`, and `p` don't need to be pointers

Comment: @yano They actually do based on the full task description. Because eventually the `read_matrices` function needs to read the dimensions from input (file I think) and return those to the caller.

Comment: The file is a text file, so a line like `*m = fgetc(fptr);` is not going to work as intended. Before you go off writing 100s of lines of code, you need to test the basics. Read the file and print what you read.

Comment: @kaylum then put them in auto storage and pass the addresses to the `read_matrices` function. Allocating single-sized fields is silly IMO.

Comment: @yano True. I was only commenting on the pointer part. But you're right that "real" code would get the address of an auto variable and not malloc those.

Comment: Better yet, write the code in terms of a macro `#define TwoDSubscript(arr, wid, i, j) (*(arr + i * wid + j))`.  Then, whenever you would have written `arr[i][j]` if `arr` were a 2-dimensional array, write `TwoDSubscript(arr, wid, i, j)`, where `wid` is the "width" of the array.  Then you won't even need to rewrite it at the end to get rid of the brackets.  (And if your instructor accuses you of "cheating" — well, then, he truly is a sadist, because all you've done is make things easier on yourself, which is a super-important key skill in programming.)

Comment: So - as others have said this is an incredibly complicated code/assignment you have here. After 5 minutes of review I don't see any use of pointers which is fundamentally wrong, you most likely have a small arithmetic error somewhere. I suggest simplifying your code significantly, and finding out why B[1][1] isn't setting properly, if it's an allocation issue or a setting issue. Try setting that alone, try setting all other values to, say, 100, try printing it alone, etc. It's probably some small math error in one of your numerous "for" loops

Comment: @user3386109 That's my advice, too — but before you can read the file, you need to allocate the array to read it into, and that's where the poor OP is stuck.

Comment: @SteveSummit You can read then print, read then print. No need to store anything.

Comment: @redwood I'm not sure why your allocation code isn't working, but there's not much point fixing it, because it doesn't meet your requirements.  You're allocating a simulated two-dimensional array, using pointers to pointers, `int **A`.  But you're supposed to implement a *flattened*, even-more-simulated array, using a single level of pointer, `int *A`.

Comment: See [question 6.16](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/dynmuldimary.html) in the [C FAQ list](http://c-faq.com/).  So far you are trying to implement something like its `array1`.  But you are supposed to use something like its `array3`.

Comment: @SteveSummit: The statement “Trying to write it otherwise accomplishes nothing except…” is false. Some students who use only subscript notation will learn only the abstraction and not the implementation, at least not for some time. Requiring students to use pointer notation requires them to learn how multidimensional arrays are laid out in memory and gives them practice. Humans do not learn merely by hearing a fact once and incorporating it holistically into their knowledge. They need practice and different experiences to train their brains and to make the learning last longer…

Comment: … As I have noted before, repetitive exercises and writing wasteful code that is no use in production code is analogous to exercising by lifting weights. Lifting weights is repetitive and accomplishes no useful net displacement of the weights; it leaves the weights exactly where they started. Any employee caught lifting objects and putting them back in the same places in a work environment instead of doing productive work would be fired. By in a gym, repetitive labor trains muscles. In a computer lab, repetitive drudgery coding trains brains.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Your points are well taken, and I had already thought better of my comment in the context of this question, and deleted it.  However: notation *does* matter.  I remember a time when I thought that introducing "simplifying" notations such as *u = i + j × k* into a complicated algebraic reduction was "cheating".  I remember covering pages and pages of paper with longhand expansions which ended up being *impossible* to get right.  There was a reason, I eventually realized, why my instructors used those "simplifying" reductions: they weren't being lazy, they were being smart.

Comment: So while I agree it's important for students to learn by doing, sometimes by rote, in order to develop the intellectual equivalent of "muscle memory" — there is a time and a place.  Sometimes, an artificial pedagogical constraint motivates and fosters some important learning.  But sometimes it's just punitive.

Comment: And just as it's important to learn how to do things the "hard way", it's also important to learn how to do them the *easy* way!  Many beginning programmers, I fear, who have been exposed only to instructors who I have been, perhaps too harshly, labeling as "sadistic", never learn this skill.  Programming can be refreshing easy, fun, and beautiful — but you'd never know it based on the way some teachers teach.  (But this is increasingly off-topic, and I'll try to stop now.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the function signatures you're supposed to use, you need to implement your 2D arrays as 1D with the correct index math.  This will result in all memory being laid out contiguously, which is not at all guaranteed with the way you're allocating memory now (two calls to `malloc` for each matrix).  For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void print_matrix(int* A, int rows, int cols)
{
  for (int r=0; r<rows; r++)
  {
    for (int c=0; c<cols; c++)
    {
      // If you want to treat A as a 2D matrix, this is where we have to do a bit of
      // fancy index math to give you what double bracket notation [][] does for you
      //    r * cols gives you the index of the right row
      //      + c give you the column offset in that row
      //        add that offset to A then dereference
      printf("%d\t", *(A + (r * cols + c)));
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}

int main(void)
{
  // matrix A is supposed to be m by n
  int* A;
  // read these from file, or where ever they're supposed to come from
  int m = 2;
  int n = 10;
  // Allocate the memory in one chunk. This makes the memory all contiguous, just the
  // same as if you had done A[m][n]. However, the double call malloc for each int**
  // matrix probably will not give you contiguous memory for the entire matrix. Each
  // call to malloc is independent.
  A = malloc(m * n * sizeof(int)); // or sizeof(*A) would be even better
  if (A == NULL)
  {
      // handle error
  }

  // We can initialize values for A at this point, still not needing to care about
  // rows or columns
  for (int i=0; i<m*n; i++)
  {
    *(A + i) = i;  // using i for a better visual when we print
  }

  print_matrix(A, m, n);
  free(A);

  return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/GTh4EfrcK)

Comment: do not use types in sizeof. Use **objects**

Comment: Use the correct type for sizes

Comment: @0___________ I made a note in the comment using the object size is better. Using 1D instead of 2D and `int`s are all requirements, look at the function prototypes given.

Comment: If function prototypes were given by the teacher he/she should be sacked instantly because of of his/her incompetence

Comment: @0___________ They were indeed, OP says p2.h was given by the instructor. I agree its a silly requirement, but as Eric suggests in the comments, it's probably a task in making students consider memory layout.

Comment: @0___________ See ongoing debate between Eric P. and me in comments in main question.  I had initially labeled instructor as "incompetent", also.  But "flattening" a 2D array to 1D is not a completely useless technique (it's routinely used in GPU programming, for example), and if you're using a "flattened" array, it does make sense to use pure pointer arithmetic to access it; bracket notation doesn't buy you much at that point.

Comment: @SteveSummit array is always flat, despite numbers of dimensions. Arrays of pointers are not flat. Do not mix those terms.

Comment: @SteveSummit  https://godbolt.org/z/PYj8W7nTz  I see the difference in readability - ie how it is prone to errors.

Comment: @0___________ I'm not going to get into a debate about array terminology, but the technique the OP is required to use does *not* involve any arrays of pointers.

Comment: @SteveSummit I am not commenting OPs task, only your comment. You claim in your comment that many-dimensional arrays are not flat. It is not true. You do not have to simulate xD arrays with 1D array as they are **flat** and can be indexed "normal" bracket way, which is much easier for humans to read

Comment: @0___________ As I said, I am not going to get into a debate about whether multi-dimensional arrays in C are or aren't "flat".  But that's beside the point.  The OP does in fact have to simulate 2D arrays with 1D, and will not be able to index them with brackets, despite being harder to read that way.  In a comment I suggested introducing a `TwoDSubscript()` macro which may or may not be palatable.

Comment: @SteveSummit then what was thepoint of your comment?

Comment: Wow, I'm pretty embarrassed I didn't think of that. I think I got caught up in all the constraints for the assignment that my brain was thinking too rigidly. Anyway, thank you so much for answering!!

Answer (score 0):

You are ovecomplicating simple things. Use pointers to arrays and allocate 2D array.

Use the correct type of your size variables.

Try to avoid side effects. Use parameters and function return values.

```
//this function is for the test purposes only
int writefile(const char *fn)
{
    FILE *fo = fopen(fn, "w");
    fprintf(fo, 
    "3\n"
    "2\n"
    "4\n"
    "1 2\n"
    "3 4\n"
    "5 6\n"
    "7 8 9 10\n"
    "11 12 13 14\n");
    fclose(fo);
}

void *allocIntMatrix(size_t rows, size_t cols)
{
    int (*m)[cols] = malloc(rows * sizeof(*m));
    return m;
}

void printIntMatrix(size_t rows, size_t cols, int (*m)[cols])
{
    for(size_t row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        for(size_t col = 0; col < cols; col++)
        {
            printf("[%5d] ", m[row][col]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int readData(FILE *fi, size_t rows, size_t cols, int (*m)[cols])
{
    for(size_t row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        for(size_t col = 0; col < cols; col++)
        {
            fscanf(fi, "%d", &m[row][col]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    size_t n,m,p;

    writefile("a.aaa");

    FILE *fi = fopen("a.aaa", "r");
    fscanf(fi, "%zu", &m);
    fscanf(fi, "%zu", &n);
    fscanf(fi, "%zu", &p);

    printf("n = %zu, m = %zu, p = %zu\n", n, m, p);

    int (*A)[n] = allocIntMatrix(m, n);
    int (*B)[p] = allocIntMatrix(n, p);

    readData(fi, m, n, A);
    readData(fi, n, p, B);

    fclose(fi);

    printIntMatrix(m, n, A);
    printf("\n");
    printIntMatrix(n, p, B);

    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/adoEx1r4f

You need to check for errors (file, memory etc). I skipped it for the sake of simplicity of the example.

Comment: violates "Cannot use square brackets anywhere in code.."

Comment: @yano I have not noticed that. If I have, I would not waste my time answering it makes no sense at all.